# Como colocar um valor default em um campo int no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Gostaria que o próprio `SGBD`, no caso MySQL colocasse um valor `default` em uma coluna da minha tabela, como acontece no `MSSQL`, isso é possível?

Por exemplo, uma das colunas da tabela é um campo `flag`, queria que ao criar uma linha ele colocasse 0 nesta campo, caso não viesse nada no comando `INSERT`.

Tem como fazer isso?

No MSSQL eu usaria o comando:

```
ALTER TABLE SaidaVeiculos 
 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_FlagAutorizado DEFAULT(0) FOR FlagAutorizado;
```

E no mysql, qual é o comando?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível, como [descrito na documentação oficial do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html), exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  i     INT DEFAULT -1,
  c     VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '',
  price DOUBLE(16,2) DEFAULT 0.00
);
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [11.6 Data Type Default Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)</sup>

Com o comando *ADD COLUMN*:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name INT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Com o comando *ALTER COLUMN*:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT 'literal';
```

Outros exemplos:

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN stocks integer SET DEFAULT 0;
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER available SET DEFAULT true;
```

<sup>***Referencia***: [How to alter a column and change the default](https://value?https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907555/6797930)</sup>

***Referencias:***

- [SQL DEFAULT Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)
- [Changing a Column’s Default Value](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch08s05.html)
- [How to alter a column and change the default](https://value?https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907555/6797930)
- [11.6 Data Type Default Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)
- [How to Add a Default Value to a Column in MySQL](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-add-a-default-value-to-a-column-in-mysql)